# Model migrations using Django (cant migrate)

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to migrate some model classes to the built-in Django SQL database admin, but I'm getting a `TypeError` when I try to migrate. What am I doing wrong?

[image: The error and my code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to stackoverflow!

Whenever you declare a foreign key in Django models, you are **required** to define what Django should do if the referenced entity is deleted.

According to Django documentation:

> A many-to-one relationship. Requires two positional arguments: the class to which the model is related and the on_delete option.

You can read more about it here [Django Official Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey)

To solve your problem simply add a on_delete attribute to your foreign keys like:

```py
topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: Thank you I will remember this for next time

Answer (score 0):

looks like it required "on_delete" arg, try with:

```
line 16: topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```